# CSS fade out transition between pages

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'd like to make a transition between two pages using only CSS.

I tried two solutions :

1. Once we clic on the button I use the pseuo element "active" and I create a transition with the opacity of my .body (.full_width in my case) to make disappear the whole page.

```
.button {
&:active + .full_width {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s;
}
}
```

When I try this CSS without the condition it works perfectly, my page beautifully disappears. But when I put the "active" condition it's not working.

2. I created a :after of my button with no content, but a background that takes the whole screen

```
.button::after {
    content:'';
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #DFE3E5;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

And then, when I activate the button, I change the z-index to bring the ::after in the foreground and change the opacity. The animation works perfectly once again, but my link doesn't work. It doesn't load the new page.

```
.button:active::after
{
    z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve my issue ? I am so close it's very frustrating ^^

Thank you !

Comment: Want to add a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: I’m not clear how one page can influence how another page is brought in, could you show your code.